# How do make HTML page load after AngularJS gets response from database?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http

I have a table on an HTML page where the data is stored in a database. I want the table or the whole page to be loaded only after the data is received. Can I do this?

AngularJS Code:

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("controller", function($scope, $http) {         
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'updateCoins.php',
    data: {get: 1},
}).then(function(response){
 $scope.db = response.data;
});
});
```

The table gets filled like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{db[0]['percent']}}%</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Is this not working in some way?  Is the AJAX call successful?  What's in `response`?

Comment: Just read the docs about ngIf ngHide ngShow, too basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you'd use a resolve with your router for this. You can also do something like this:

angular.module("app", []).controller("controller", function($scope, $http) {

```
$scope.dataLoaded = false        
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'updateCoins.php',
    data: {get: 1},
}).then(function(response){
 $scope.db = response.data;
 $scope.dataLoaded = true
});
});
```

Then in your html on the outermost element where you load your controller use ng-if="dataLoaded"

Comment: It doesn't work if I put `ng-if="dataLoaded"` in the element where I user ng-controller (the whole page is blank), but works if I do it for the element directly below it.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way if you're not using ngRoute or ui.router with resolves is to have a variable set before. Examples:

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("controller", function($scope, $http) {         
    $scope.hasCompleted = false;
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'updateCoins.php',
        data: {get: 1},
    }).then(function(response){
        $scope.db = response.data;
        $scope.hasCompleted = true;
    });
});

<tr>
    <td ng-show="hasCompleted">{{db[0]['percent']}}%</td>
 </tr>
```